# The problem with the texture is due to the UV scan

Tags: texturing

I'm a beginner and I have a problem with the texture due to UV scanning.
[image]
At the place of the seam, the texture is distorted and, accordingly, when working with a brush, it is not smooth and blurs.

[image]

I found a solution to this particular problem,
[image]
but another one immediately arises because of which the ladder is too visible at certain sections of the line.
[image]
I will be glad to help. (written with the help of an interpreter, sorry for the inconvenience if there are any (rus))

Comment: if you're not glad with the current unwrap, maybe re-unwrap this part or change its scale in the UV Editor?

Comment: In the second version of the UV scan, I was almost able to achieve the desired result by stretching, but not without problems. I wrote here hoping for help to find a solution that is the best, which most likely I did not find.

Comment: have you tried to increase the size of the image?

Comment: Increased from 2048 to 4096 px. But this way I hide the symptoms rather than get rid of them. but I still can't understand what the problem is in general. Do I need to make more stitches in certain places? It's just that the person who made the training video is doing well (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBMbMw-ME5g&list=PLuuJ7EJSjEfMETY8txzRpXHPH08Eg7kA6&index=32) (yes, it's in Russian, but just look at 2: 25) (a video where he made a UV scan and applied a texture https://youtu.be/FvZbdbQM-qs?list=PLuuJ7EJSjEfMETY8txzRpXHPH08Eg7kA6&t=244) while I have a major problem here.

Comment: maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here, I hope I did everything right.
https://pasteall.org/blend/da2db91226c64b37ad9d63b3bf66ba07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put an additional edge loop it will fix the problem, it must be the highly stretched face that creates the problem:

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Wow, I would never have thought that this is how it is solved. Thank you very much!
If there is a way to thank you (put a like somewhere, etc.), then please tell me.

Comment: to validate an answer you just need to click on the validate icon on the left of my answer

Comment: I did it, thank you very much again.